# Count number of orders from users who order on multiple sites

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an orders table that stores orders from multiple sites within our company. In the table we have the fields userid, ordernumber and sitename.  What I'd like to be able to get is the number of users who have orded from  2 or more of our sites.

This is what I started with:

```
SELECT
  o.ordernumber,
  o.sitename,
  o.userdbid,
  o2.sitename,
  o2.userdbid,
  o2.ordernumber
FROM
  orders o
INNER JOIN
  orders o2
ON
  o.userdbid = o2.userdbid
WHERE
  o.sitename != o2.sitename
ORDER BY
  o.userdbid;
```

This isn't close to correct but this as close as I could think to get. Any help or direction would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Can you please show sample and desired results so we know what answer your query was trying to get.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need a `HAVING` clause to compare the aggregate `COUNT()` to 2, wherein you have grouped by `userbid`.  Be sure to use `DISTINCT` in your aggregate `COUNT()` so that you get multiple sites rather than just multiple orders.

```
SELECT
  o.userbid,
  COUNT(DISTINCT o.sitename) AS num_order_sites
FROM
  orders o
GROUP BY o.userbid
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT o.sitename) >= 2
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking just for users who have ordered from more than one site you don't actually need to do a self join. You just need this.

```
SELECT
  o.userdbid
FROM
  orders o
GROUP BY o.userdbid
HAVING 
    COUNT(o.sitename) > 1
```

If you want to then find additional information you can join back to these results.

e.g.

```
SELECT 
     o.ordernumber,
     o.sitename,
     o.userdbid
FROM   orders o 
   INNER JOIN (SELECT o.userdbid 
               FROM   orders o 
               GROUP  BY o.userdbid 
               HAVING Count( DISTINCT o.sitename) > 1) morethanOne 
           ON o.userdbid = morethanone.o.userdbid
```

UPDATE: Plese note [Michael's point](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11508997/119477) about DISTINCT

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4c629/21)

Comment: Thanks Conrad, I chose Michaels answer as it was a little bit closer and he answered first(or at least it showed at the top first). I upvoted you for the help, Thanks!

Comment: @iangraham I appreciate your comment and I get why you picked Michael's answer (I messed up in more than one way), but explaining votes or accepts has a tendency to get ugly. It might be best not to mention it at all.